# How to Tar/GZip just the files folders in the data directory?

Tags: linux, bash, backup, tar, gzip

I have a bunch of folders and files in `/usr/local/bin/data` that I want to `tar.gz`.

I have a bash script that sets the source folder to backup `src='/usr/local/bin/data/*`

When I open up the `.tar.gz` file, it shows me the folder usr, then local, then bin, then data, etc..

How can I have it tar just the files/folders starting in `/data/`?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `-C` option in Tar:

```
tar -C /usr/local/bin/ -cvzf foo.tar.gz data
```